# Android: How to get Bluetooth scanning status?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Here's how I start scanning BLE devices

```
    if(bluetoothLeScanner!=null) {
        bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanCallback);
        isScanning = true;
    }
```

How and when do I set `isScanning` to false?

Is there a way to find it inside of `scanCallback`?

```
private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, final ScanResult result) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
        if(result==null) return;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bluetoothDeviceAdapter.update(result.getDevice());
                bluetoothDeviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        // This doesn't mean end of scan does it?
        // isScanning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
        super.onBatchScanResults(results);
        final List<BluetoothDevice> deviceList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(ScanResult result: results)
            deviceList.add(result.getDevice());
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bluetoothDeviceAdapter.updateBatch(deviceList);
                bluetoothDeviceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        // This doesn't mean end of scan does it?
        // isScanning = false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scan runs until

1. You explicitly stop it.
2. The onScanFailed callback is called.
3. Bluetooth is turned off.